# Efficient way to convert dictionary of list to pair list of key and value

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I have dictionary of list as follows (it can be more than 1M elements, also assume dictionary is sorted by key)

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
d = {0: [0,1], 1: [1,2,3], 
     2: [3,4,5], 3: [4,5,6], 
     4: [5,6,7], 5: [7], 
     6: [7,8,9]}
```

I want to know what is the most efficient way (fastest way for large dictionary) to convert it into list of row and column index like:

```
r_index = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6]
c_index = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9]
```

Here are some solutions that I have so far:

1. Using iteration

   ```
   row_ind = [k for k, v in d.iteritems() for _ in range(len(v))] # or d.items() in Python 3
   col_ind = [i for ids in d.values() for i in ids]
   ```
2. Using pandas library

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
   df = df.stack().reset_index()
   row_ind = list(df['level_0'])
   col_ind = list(df[0])
   ```
3. Using itertools

   ```
   import itertools
   indices = [(x,y) for x, y in itertools.chain.from_iterable([itertools.product((k,), v) for k, v in d.items()])]
   indices = np.array(indices)
   row_ind = indices[:, 0]
   col_ind = indices[:, 1]
   ```

I'm not sure which way is the fastest way to deal with this problem if I have a lot of elements in my dictionary. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: *Efficient* in what terms?  Lines of code?  Execution time?  Maintainability?  Access level?  Other?

Comment: @nbryans One example is to transform this is to sparse matrix i.e. `csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind))`. I also want to insert this format into SQL table using pandas. Plain list format will be in the format that easier to work with.

Comment: @Prune Sorry, I should say 'fastest' way to execute this (execution time). Not efficient. I will change the title right now.

Comment: So why not measured the time on your own and post it here? This thread might fit better for stackexchange.

Comment: @Markus I can do that too. However, I'm just not sure if timing in this small example will work with larger scale of dictionary that I have. Basically, I have tiny knowledge about how the code will scale.

Comment: `dict` is not ordered so there is no way you can guarantee the order that items are iterated or that the resulting lists index anything sensibly.

Comment: @tdelaney Do I have to convert dictionary to OrderedDict or sort dictionary before? Anyhow, you can assume that dictionary is sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule of thumb of optimization in python is, to make sure that your innermost loop is outsourced to some library function. This only applies for cpython - pypy is a completely different story.
In your case using extend is giving some significant speedup.

```
import time
l = range(10000)
x = dict([(k, list(l)) for k in range(1000)])

def org(d):
    row_ind = [k for k, v in d.items() for _ in range(len(v))]
    col_ind = [i for ids in d.values() for i in ids]

def ext(d):
    row_ind = [k for k, v in d.items() for _ in range(len(v))]
    col_ind = []
    for ids in d.values():
        col_ind.extend(ids)

def ext_both(d):
    row_ind = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        row_ind.extend([k] * len(v))
    col_ind = []
    for ids in d.values():
        col_ind.extend(ids)

functions = [org, ext, ext_both]
for func in functions:
    begin = time.time()
    func(x)
    elapsed = time.time() - begin
    print(func.__name__ + ": "  + str(elapsed))
```

Output when using python2:

```
org: 0.512559890747
ext: 0.340406894684
ext_both: 0.149670124054
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the input size for the benchmark:

```
import time
l = xrange(10000)
x = dict([(k, list(l)) for k in xrange(1000)])


def f(d):
    row_ind = [k for k, v in d.iteritems() for _ in range(len(v))]
    col_ind = [i for ids in d.values() for i in ids]


def ff(d):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
    df = df.stack().reset_index()
    row_ind = list(df['level_0'])
    col_ind = list(df[0])


def fff(d):
    import itertools
    import numpy as np
    indices = [(x, y) for x, y in itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        [itertools.product((k,), v) for k, v in d.items()])]
    indices = np.array(indices)
    row_ind = indices[:, 0]
    col_ind = indices[:, 1]

alternatives = [f, ff, fff]
for func in alternatives:
    begin = time.time()
    func(x)
    print time.time() - begin
```

output:

```
0.977538108826
5.26920008659
6.98472499847
```

With the current sample size, the first approach seems better. But if you have more time to select your sample size and wait for the execution to finish, there might be a different result. Chances are it's better to use libraries.

Comment: Thanks so much for the testing snippet @kardaj! I have the same problem that I don't know which code will run fastest at larger scale.

Comment: Not sure of exactly the use case, but it may or may not be fair to include `import` time in those comparisons, and I know for things like `pandas` and `numpy`, `import`-ing can take a little time. Doesn't look like it would much change the outcomes in this case, but figured I'd mention that it's something to consider.

Answer (score -2):

There is a function called a *decorator*. The decorator is always above a def or class function. Use `import timer  @timer.Timer()` or something like that over your code. You can Google more. Or go to this link: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators

Comment: What do decorators have to do with any of this?